# How to do feature selection with randomForest package?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I'm using randomForest in order to find out the most significant variables. I was expecting some output that defines the accuracy of the model and also ranks the variables based on their importance. But I am a bit confused now. I tried randomForest and then ran `importance()` to extract the importance of variables.
But then I saw another command `rfcv` (Random Forest Cross-Valdidation for feature selection), which should be the most appropriate for this purpose I suppose, but the question I have regarding this is: how to get the list of the most important variables? How to see the output after running it? Which command to use?

Another thing: What is the difference between `randomForest` and `predict.randomForest`?

I am not very familiar with randomforest and R therefore any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have made a `randomForest` model you use `predict.randomForest` to use the model you created on new data e.g. build a random forest with training data then run your validation data through that model with `predict.randomForest`.

As for the rfcv there is an option `recursive` which (from the help):

> whether variable importance is (re-)assessed at each step of variable
>   reduction

Its all in the [help file](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf)

Comment: No, it's not all in the help file. `rfcv(... recursive=T)` option still never actually tells you what the individual variable importances are, at any point. So it's totally useless for feature-selection! The only thing `rfcv` does is estimate CV error as a function of n.var, the number of variables; which is nearly useless. As to using raw feature importance for variable selection, that is full of pitfalls, esp. with highly-correlated variables. So don't rely on either for feature-selection. Use one of the other packages.